# search expression returns four null elements

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

i am new to `Xpath`, and i was following a tutorial to search for some target data in xml file, and i wrote the following code according to the below posted xml file. and as shown in the posted results below, i got a nodeList populated with four null elements, and i expected the NodeList to be populated with four emails as my search expression is

`String expression1 = "/Employees//Employee[position()<=4]//email";`

please let me know why i am getting four null elements

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;

    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("c:\\xml0.xml"));
    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String expression1 = "/Employees//Employee[position()<=4]//email";

    String email = xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(document);
    System.out.println(email);

    Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(0));
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(1));
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(2));
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(3));

}
```

**Xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Employees>
<Employee emplid="1111" type="admin">
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Watson</lastname>
    <age>30</age>
    <email>johnwatson@sh.com</email>
   </Employee>

<Employee emplid="2222" type="admin">
    <firstname>Sherlock</firstname>
    <lastname>Homes</lastname>
    <age>32</age>
    <email>sherlock@sh.com</email>
</Employee>

<Employee emplid="4444" type="user">
    <firstname>Jim</firstname>
    <lastname>Moriarty</lastname>
    <age>52</age>
    <email>jim@sh00.com</email>
</Employee>

<Employee emplid="4444" type="user">
    <firstname>Jim</firstname>
    <lastname>Moriarty</lastname>
    <age>52</age>
    <email>jim@sh33.com</email>
</Employee>

<Employee emplid="5555" type="admin">
    <firstname>Mycroft</firstname>
    <lastname>Holmes</lastname>
    <age>41</age>
    <email>mycroft@sh.com</email>
</Employee>

</Employees>
```

**Results**:

```
johnwatson@sh.com
4
[email: null]
[email: null]
[email: null]
[email: null]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need "/Employees//Employee[position()<=4]//email" in this XML. The '//' means any descendant but in this XML the Employee is a direct child of Employees, meaning a simple '/' would do.

The output is not null to be clear. The output is the node element 'email', which is what you requested after all.

To get the text values you need to use:
"/Employees/Employee[position()<=4]/email/text()"

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `/text()` in your expression. try to change it to

```
String expression1 = "/Employees//Employee[position()<=5]/email/text()";
```

otherwise, the code looks fine to me